# Ignoring part of a list in the output of a func. call in Perl

Tags: perl

I would like to only capture part of a list output by a function in Perl.

I thought something alone these lines would do it, but they don't.

E.g. Capturing the last element of the list:

```
(, $my_var)  = split(/_/,$sample_string);
```

E.g. Capturing the second element of the list:

```
(, $my_var, , ,)  = split(/_/,$sample_string);
```

Is this possible in Perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second element of the return array:

```
my $second_element = (split(/_/,$sample_string))[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution: assign undesired elements to `undef`:

```
(undef, $my_var)  = split(/_/,$sample_string);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why find all the underscores when you only need to find two?

```
my ($last_element)   = $sample_string =~ /([^_]*)\z/;
my ($second_element) = $sample_string =~ /_([^_]*)_/;
```

More generally, a list slice would do:

```
my $last_element   = ( split(/_/, $sample_string) )[-1];
my $second_element = ( split(/_/, $sample_string) )[1];
my @some           = ( split(/_/, $sample_string) )[2,3];
```

But the closest to what you requested is placeholders:

```
my (undef, $second_element) = split(/_/, $sample_string);
```